# Example of a Noetherian UFD that is not a Dedekind domain.

Tags: ring-theory

I am having trouble finding one example of a Noetherian UFD that is not a Dedekind domain. Or maybe a Noetherian UFD is always a Dedekind domain and henceforth a PID.

Comment: I cannot believe that in the search for an example you did not consider a polynomial ring in more than one variable over a field...

Answer (score 1):

The [DaRT query](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=64l&H=114&L=111) has an example: $\mathbb Z[x]$.

You could have come upon this yourself reading the wiki article, where it states that Dedekind Domains have dimension less than $2$, whereas the example has dimension $2$.